# How to change Port 8080 on Apache Tomcat on Linux Centos 6.5 server to the Default?

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, geoserver

I want to remove switch from port 8080 on my Apache Tomcat on Linux server CentOS 6.5 to the default. On My hosted Apache Tomcat server is running on port 8080 on url vmx15978.hosting24.com.au:8080. After I have installed the Geoserver software on the Apache server the url for it is http://vmx15978.hosting24.com.au:8080/geoserver/web/.

My website domain is links-map.com. Currently I can access Geoserver by this URL: links-map.com:8080/geoserver/web; However, I want to access Geoserver without 8080 using this URL instead: http://links-map.com/geoserver/web/

Comment: This sounds like a question for [Server fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. It means I need to change port number from 8080 to 80 so that I can access my url (e.g `www.mydomain.com`) without appending 8080. But I found a different way to solve the problem.
Instead of changing port number in `server.xml`. I **redirected port number 80 to 8080** using the following script. This works perfectly fine for me.

```
[root@myroot ~]# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
[root@myroot ~]# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Please find more at this [link](http://www.davidghedini.com/pg/entry/install_tomcat_7_on_centos)

Answer (score 7):

taken from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/)

in your tomcat install dir, look for `server.xml` file.

change

```
<Connector port="8080" ...
```

to

```
<Connector port="80" ....
```

or any other port (80 is the default without specifying port)

don't forget to restart tomcat to apply changes

```
sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

Comment: I have change port 8080 to  80 on  <Connector port="80" .... But nothing  is found on vmx15978.hosting24.com.au my tomcat server is 7.0.42

Comment: thank a lot dear friend. i was strugling really hard for this. a simple trick of changin 8080 to 80 worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Even after changing port `8080` to `80` we won't be able to access tomcat with it, as 80 is a privileged port, so it should be run by root,

Hence we can change Tomcat user to `root` as below and issue will be resolved, now we will be able to open tomcat site without 8080.

```
$ cat /etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf |grep USER

TOMCAT_USER="root"
```

Note: It is not recommended to run tomcat with root user.