# How to change and start tomcat port in Linux server

Tags: linux, tomcat

I tried to change the server.xml in the Tomcat7 from port=8080 to 8088.

When i start the server using ./startup.sh and then when i hit the URL http://:8088/
i get an error No Route to Host.

JBoss is already running on 8080 , so i want to run tomcat in a different port.

Comment: Shouln't the URL be, `http://localhost:8088/` ?

Comment: I am not running this in my local. Im deploying my application to a unix box

Comment: You could check this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558810/how-to-change-port-8080-on-apache-tomcat-on-linux-centos-6-5-sever-to-the-defaul?rq=1)

Comment: I just tried to start the server. It gives the following output [root@CTSC00258263606 bin]# ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.39
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.39
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/jdk1.6.0_45
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Comment: ---- Here i did not get the message like server started. when i tried ps -ef command the process does not show pid. Whats the problem here. why my server is not starting

Comment: Try starting the server with `catalina.sh run`. With this you can see all the output from the server and you'll surely find out the error (be sure to check the output with caution). Good luck!